# Lower bound and monotonocally decreasing functions

Tags: calculus

I may be missing something quite obvious, but why does it follow that if $$(d/dx)(f(x)+{g(x)\over x^2 })<0$$ then for some $a>0$, we can say $$f(0)>{g(a)\over a^2 }$$?

---

Sorry about my missing the $d/dx $ previously!!

Comment: What other assumptions do you have on $f,g$?

Comment: Does $f(x) = -2 - x$ and $g(x) = x^2$ serve as a counterexample?

Comment: @ChristopherWong: Sorry about the typo! I hve corrected it.

Comment: @HerngYi: You are right. I'm sorry I left out the $d/dx$!

Comment: @Syd, I have changed my counterexample, see my previous comment

Comment: @HerngYi: Thank you :) What if $f>0$? Would it be true then?

Comment: @Syd, where did the question come from, and why (or under what circumstances) should it be true? It just seems so arbitrary that I immediately tried to find a counterexample, and I could.

Comment: $f\gt0$ won't do --- let $f(x)=(1/2)e^{-x}$, $g(x)=x^2$. So, what makes you think that inequality holds?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I was told in physics class to show that $$p(x)+m^2(x)/x^4$$ is decreasing in $x$ -- where $p$ is pressure $m$ is mass an $x$ measures distance from the center of the star concerned. This part I have done. It is then said that I should be able to deduce that a lower bound for the pressure at $x=0$ is $m^2(a)/a^4$ where $a$ is the radius of the star.

Comment: @HerngYi: That is a very valid concern. I have added the context in the comment above.

Comment: Syd, maybe there's some relation between $p$ and $m$ that you're not taking into account, or some other property of $p$ and/or $m$ implied by the physics that needs to be incorporated into the mathematics. Also, $m^2/x^4$ isn't the same thing as $g/x^2$, although I don't think that's what's causing the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

What is sure is that since

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)+\frac{g(x)}{x^2}\right) < 0$$

the function 
$$h(x) \equiv f(x)+\frac{g(x)}{x^2}$$

is decreasing. And thus, $\forall a>b$ (if $h(a)$ and $h(b)$ exist) we have

$$h(a) < h(b)$$

and thus, if $a>0$ and $b\to 0$

$$h(a) < \lim_{x\to 0} h(x)$$

But this only leads to something like

$$f(a)+\frac{g(a)}{a^2} < f(0) + \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)}{x^2}$$

and doesn't explain everything